# Gradle sinc failed with kotlin extension. for input string : " " in build.gradle file module(app)

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]I am getting the following error, when i try to build my application. It is already build with kotlin extension.but suddenly it gives me this error.

> Gradle sync failed: For input string: "     " and it pointing to build.gradle apply plugin:'kotlin-android' line.

Comment: could you past you gradle file

Comment: i have added the image, please check.

Comment: i am facing this issue again... any solution is appriciated